# Can a player character avoid dying as long as they still have Plot Points?

Tags: character-death, cortex-prime

I've read Cortex Prime and now I'm wondering whether a PC could die. The rule said that *"you can spend a PP to avoid being taken out of the scene"* (which I translate as dying).

**Does this mean that as long as a player still has PP, they can't die if they don't wish so?**

Comment: Sounds like plot armor to me

Answer (score 4):

As I understand it, being "taken out" means that the character is no longer an active participant in a **scene**. They're not dead, just temporarily incapable of action.

> When a character is taken out, they may no longer perform any test or contest and no longer participates in the scene. (pg. 22, "Cortex Prime Game Handbook")

So to answer your question: yes, while they still have plot points, a character can't die. But even if they *do* run out of plot points, they're still not dead: they're just sitting on the sidelines for a while.

As for **permanent death**, there are three mods in the Game Handbook that mention it:

1. #### Trauma (pg. 41):

> Once trauma is stepped up beyond 12, the character is permanently out of options—they’re dead, hopelessly incoherent, lost to their own psyche, or whatever seems most appropriate.

2. #### Ablative Life Points (pg. 43):

> Without some first aid or intervention, the player must spend a PP to keep them alive, and any additional damage taken by the PC forces the same PP spend until the total negative amount of damage is equal to the original life point score. If this happens, the PC is dead.

3. #### Threshold Life Points (pg. 43):

> If the accumulated wounds and stun, added together, exceed the life point score, the PC is unconscious. This includes having no wounds and stun that exceeds the life point score all by itself.
>
> If the total wounds (not counting stun) exceed the life point score, the PC is dead.